# Observable array not displayed in knockout even though it rendered

Tags: knockout.js, drop-down-menu

When entering an E-mail address, the user will have to select the E-mail 
 domain from the pre-defined list (e.g., gmail.com; outlook.com; hotmail.com).

HTML:

```
<!-- Mulitple array of emails   -->
<div>
   <table class="table table-bordered">
      <tbody data-bind='foreach: billDeliveryEmails'>
         <tr>
            <td><input class='required' data-bind='value: userName' /></td>
            <td><select data-bind="options: $root.availableEmailDomains(), value: domainName, optionsText: 'domainName', optionsValue: 'domainName'"></select></td>
            <td><a  data-bind="click:'removeDeliveryEmailAddress'">Delete</a></td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
   <a class="atm-bloque-link" data-bind="click:'addDeliveryEmailAddress'">Agregue otra direccion de email</a>
</div>
```

VM:

```
billDeliveryEmails : [],
availableEmailDomains: ko.observableArray(['gmail.com','yahoo.com','hotmail.com','outlook.com','hotmail.es','yahoo.es'])


 addDeliveryEmailAddress: function ($element, data, context, bindingContext, event) {

        bindingContext.$root.billDeliveryEmails.push({
            userName: "",
            domainName: this.viewModel.get('availableEmailDomains')[0]
        });

        event.preventDefault();
    },

    removeDeliveryEmailAddress: function ($element, data, context, bindingContext, event) {

        bindingContext.$root.billDeliveryEmails.splice(0, 1)
        event.preventDefault();
    }
```

I get below output: even though options are rendered successfuly but they are not displayed, [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuw1x.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `select` element is binding to `availableEmailDomains` but I don't see such an object defined in your viewmodel, so I'm going to assume you meant `emailDeliveryDomains`. If this is the case, you can just change the select element to the following:

```
<td><select data-bind="options: $root.emailDeliveryDomains()"></select></td>
```

I think you may be misunderstanding how the `value`, `optionsText`, and `optionsValue` bindings work (you may want to read the [knockout documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html)). `value` should be an observable to store the selected value from the dropdown. `optionsText` and `optionsValue` are used when the array passed to the `options` binding is an array of objects. For example, if you passed an array like `[{ color: 'blue', id: 1 }, { color: 'red', id: 2}]` to the `options` binding, it would make sense to also set `optionsText: 'color'` and `optionsValue: 'id'`.

In your example, `emailDeliveryDomains` is just an array of strings, so you don't need to set `optionsValue` or `optionsText`.